# Fix string index out of range

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert the random integer used in line 13 into a string so that it can be encrypted, but it keeps saying string index out of range on Python. I'm using the latest version of Python.

```
import random
result = ''
message = ''
choice = ''
key = ''
number = random.randint(1,50)

while choice != '2':
    choice = input("would you like to 1. encrypt message or 2. exit   ")

    if choice == '1':
        message = input("enter message to be encrypted    ")
        for i in range(0, len(message)):
            result = result + chr(ord(message[i]) - number)
        number = str(number)
        for i in range(0, len(number[i])):
            key = key key + int(ord(number[i])-7)
        print(result + "    press enter to close")
        print(key)
        end = input()
        break
```

Comment: Please paste your code into the question, do not screenshot it. Also, give us the full error trace. Read up on [how to ask a good StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Yes, you are supposed to post the code, not a picture of it. But `for i in range(len(number[i]))` - what is this supposed to do?

Comment: What happens if you have a ` ` in your message and your `number` is 50... look it up here and think about it: https://ascii.cl/ when you fixed your current error

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an issue with line number 16.

```
for i in range(0, len(number[i])):
```

'i' can only be accessible inside the loop's scope. len(number[i]) does not make sense for compiler and hence an index error.
Instead try for:

```
for i in range(len(number)):
```

Best Regards